# Blazor .NET 8.0 ApiController called via HttpGet returns redirect to login html instead of using username and password in header?

Tags: blazor-server-side, basic-authentication

I have created a Blazor.Net 8.0 Server Side App.

I included some ApiController classed that require Authorization.

However, when I try and call those ApiControllers via Postman (simple HttpGet) and I pass in my basic authentication username and password, what is returned in PostMan is the Html Redirect that content - instead of using the basic authentication provided in the header?

Must I sequence the code in my program.cs differently?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

etc. 

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore .....

etc.

builder.Services.AddControllers();  

etc.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();


app.MapControllers();
// Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to make this work as follow.

1. in program.cs add this code which will only make use of basic authentication handler (custom class) when a request path starting with /api is reached:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", options =>
{
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
        {
            return "BasicAuthentication";
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

2. in the ApiController add these decorators

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "MYROLE")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication")]
```

3. use this BasicAuth handler custom class

DISCLAIMER: I am injecting a custom auth service class to obtain a custom user and roles related to the logged in user, since I am using Azure Gen 2 Storage Account Tables to store my AspNetUser, Roles tables etc, instead of SQL Server...

```
    public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly CustomAuthService _customAuthService;

        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder) : base(options, logger, encoder)
        {

        }

        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, CustomAuthService customAuthService) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _customAuthService = customAuthService;
        }


        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
                //return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");
            }


            await Task.Delay(100);

            var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);

            if (authHeader.Scheme != "Basic")
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Scheme");
            }

            var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(':');
            var username = credentials[0];
            var password = credentials[1];

            List<string> listRoles = new List<string>();
            
            try
            {
                ApplicationUser user = await _customAuthService.GetUserByNormalizedUserName(username.ToUpper());
                
                IQueryable<ApplicationRole> roles = _customAuthService.GetRoles().AsQueryable();
                IQueryable<ApplicationUserRole> userRoles = _customAuthService.GetUserRoles(user).AsQueryable();

                foreach (ApplicationUserRole x in userRoles)
                {
                    foreach (ApplicationRole y in roles) 
                    {
                        if (x.RoleId == y.Id)
                        {
                            listRoles.Add(y.NormalizedName);    
                        }
                    }                        
                }
                
            }
            catch
            {
                listRoles.Add("None"); 
            }  

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            };

            foreach(string x in listRoles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x));
            }            

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
    }
```